# Need a recursive database method/tool

Tags: database, database-schema

So I'm working on a small project where I need to store data in an almost recursive way, but I can't figure out what's the best method or tool to do so, I've already thought about using SQL or redis to do so but I don't feel like they're suitable enough.

My data will supposedly look like this

```
Person{ 
Person_ID;
Name;
Other_characteristics;
Depends_on_persons;
}
```

Where the depends on could be a single person ( a single element array with a Person_ID ) multiple people ( an array of Person_IDs not limited to any number) or no dependency at all ( an empty array ), and I'd have to sweep through all these dependent data and run a method on them recursively until I reach a terminal,
My algorithm is ready I just need to get a database to store this data and retrieve it till the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 2nd table and implement a many to many relationship to create what you need:

```
Person 
-------
PersonID PK
Name
OtherCharacteristics

PersonDependableLink
--------------------
PersonDependableLinkID - PK
PersonID - FK to Person 
DependsOnPersonID - FK to Person
```

Following data states that PersonID 1 depends on PersonIDs 2 and 3

```
Person
PersonID    Name    OtherCharacteristics
----------------------------------------
1           abc     bla bla
2           def     bla bla
3           ghi     bla bla


PersonDependableLink 
PersonDependableLinkID      PersonID    DependsOnPersonID
---------------------------------------------------------
1                           1           2
2                           1           3
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Well I thought of that, but the recursive manner of the method where every object calls its dependents makes SQL abit slow where every query would lead to another a couple more queries, but redis's key value storage is fast but I don't think it supports this kind of schema.. So I'm looking for some way

Comment: How do you want to query ? Retrive all persons who person id depends on ? going recursively ? you could do a recursive query to solve that for you and with a proper index (if needed) shouldn't be a problem.